# HTML pan and tilt input control

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, coordinates

I'd like to create an input that allows the user to drag a dot around a box and will output the 2D coordinates of that dot inside the box. This will be used to drive pan and tilt values. The picture below shows the functionality I'd like from another application:

[image: pan and tilt input]

I'd like to use this in a web application with HTML and Javascript. The center (0,0) coordinate should be in the middle of the box (where the crosshairs meet in the example above). May I have some guidance as to how to start going about creating this type of thing?

Comment: And I'd like a million dollars but I wouldn't come to Stack Overflow asking for it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I'm just looking for a starting concept like that was given below, not a full solution. My question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal,  Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in pure HTML and JS, although this problem is not a simple one so I'll just point you in the right direction.

First create a container (div) to represent the 2D grid, and dot using HTML/CSS. You can calculate the co-ordinates of the dot in relation to the container using HTMLElement.offsetTop() (although this will be co-ordinates from the top-left of the container, so you will need to do some maths if you want it to be from a different point).

For the actual dragging to happen, you will need to add mouse events (would be easiest to use jQuery for this), such as mousedown, mousemove and mouseup.

Your mousedown event will check that the mouse is over the dot when pressed, and if so, set a 'dragging' flag to true.

Your mousemove will check the cursor position whenever moved (if dragging === true), and use the mouse position to calculate co-ordinates in relation to the box (using the mouse's position in relation to the box position, which will require some maths skills). You can also alter the position of the dot to follow your mouse with CSS (if the dot has `position:absolute` style applied, you will set the `top` and `left` properties using HTMLElement.style.

Finally, mouseup will set the 'dragging' flag to false.

Like I said, this will take some time to implement and you may not do it exactly like this, but here's a basic example.